# What is the benefit between calling function inside and outside class?

Tags: python

I don't know what is the difference between the following code snippets ?

First:

```
class A:
 def __init__(self, v):
   self.v=v
 def main(self):
   self.func_A(self.v)
 def func_A(self, t):
   print t
```

When calling `func_A`:

```
A("sometext").main()
```

Second:

```
class A:
 def __init__(self, v):
   self.v=v
 def main(self):
   func_A(self.v)

def func_A(t):
  print t
```

And when calling `func_A`:

```
A("sometext").main()
```

The function calls are quite confusing to me.

Comment: `A("sometext").func_A()` will fail because you aren't passing in the mandatory argument.

Comment: I have edited some code above

Comment: Please run your code before posting. This still fails. Missing a self

Comment: Both code does the same thing @QuangVũ see if my response below makes sense!

Comment: I mean in the first code, function func_A i inside the class, and the second is outside the class.

Comment: Still the behaviour will be the same @QuangVũ check my answer below:)

Answer (score 0):

You should missing `self` in your call to `func_A(self.v)`, you should do `self.func_A(self.v)` instead

In the first example, the attribute `v` of class `A` is passed to the `main` function via `func_A(self.v)` and that gets printed

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v=v

    def func_A(self, t):
        print(t)

A("sometext").func_A('text')
```

The output will be `sometext`, since you passed `sometext` as an argument to `func_A`

In the second example does the same thing, the only difference being `func_A` is defined outside the class.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v=v

    def main(self):
        func_A(self.v)

def func_A(t):
    print(t)

A("sometext").main()
```

The output here will be `sometext` since the attribute `A.v` is set to `sometext`